# Spring data JPA doesn't accept regex query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have this method that aims to return objects using regex and pagination

```java
Page<JokeModel> searchAllByPhraseRegex(String phrase, Pageable pageable);
```

However, this would throw an exception `Unsupported keyword REGEX (1): [MatchesRegex, Matches, Regex]`

Spring Data JPA docs explicitly stated that Regex is supported:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html

Moreover, Intellij does give suggestions for completing the method:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: What database are you using? the exception thrown is that the database does not support regex operation

Comment: Oh I'm using MySQL. I just found out that it uses REGEXP and not REGEX.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738213/12881733