# Get distinct list of numbers from string column with JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

Let's say I have a database table:

```
ID     | DESCRIPTION
1      | Some value '123' added
2      | Deleted value '333' by 'Someone'
```

Jpa entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG")
public class Log {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

And working jpa query to retrieve first found numeric value inside single quotas:

```java
    @Query(value = "select distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR( log.DESCRIPTION, '''(\\d+)''',1,1,'',1) from Log log where 1=1 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findObjectIdsInDescription();
```

I'm working on Oracle database hence REGEXP_SUBSTR + native query, which is working fine for me right now.

Is there a database independent approach using jpa query only? I'm asking as I also need it for different databases.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a custom getter `Log.getIdsInDescription` where you parse the description in java yourself? Therefore, you would pull the log, then call your getter. Or do you need to extract the ids from all the logs?

Comment: I was hoping to create a solution where database handles it and returns only necessary values. But if nothing works then ofc retrieving whole content of column and parsing/filtering it in java would work.

Comment: I'm not sure. But can u check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738213/2353403

Comment: I'm getting to conclusion that string manipulation in scope of database query is dependent on database hence only native queries can solve it.