Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'containing' found for type 'String';
I am building a system to search series and store in my database, but when I tring to search a list of names of genres the flowing error is throw:
Error
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serieController': Error creating bean with name 'serieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tvSeriesApi': Error creating bean with name 'tvSeriesApi': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreService': Error creating bean with name 'genreServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreRepository': Error creating bean with name 'genreRepository' defined in com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]      
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]        
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.GeekApplication.main(GeekApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tvSeriesApi': Error creating bean with name 'tvSeriesApi': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreService': Error creating bean with name 'genreServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreRepository': Error creating bean with name 'genreRepository' defined in com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tvSeriesApi': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreService': Error creating bean with name 'genreServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreRepository': Error creating bean with name 'genreRepository' defined in com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genreServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genreRepository': Error creating bean with name 'genreRepository' defined in com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genreRepository' defined in com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]      
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:292) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]  
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.GenreRepository.findAllByNameContainingIn(java.util.List); No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:455) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:431) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:465) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:431) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:344) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:259) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:260) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:389) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
        ... 91 common frames omitted

I already try using "findAllByNameContainsIn" instand of "findAllByNameContaining".
My Repository:
public interface GenreRepository extends JpaRepository<GenreModel, Integer> {
    public List<GenreModel> findAllByNameContaining(List<String> names);
}

model:
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "genres")
public class GenreModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_genre")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name_genre")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genre")
    @Transient
    private List<MediaModel> medias;
}

Should I use JPA Specifications?
Could someone help me please? Thank you very much in advance!

Always read the stackTrace bottom up, the error is usually very clear: "Caused by: ... No property 'containing' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: GenreModel.name" The method name. Your method name should only have the property name and the operation for the "IN" as findByNameIn Also, always check the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html

I see, thanks @Jorge Campos, I revolve my problem with your comment, but I was wanting do something like REGEXP (REGEX), I was trying use something like "LIKE IN ('A', 'B')" SQL Statement, so future people can check it in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-keywords-reference.html#appendix.query.method.predicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738142/how-to-use-regex-keyword-in-spring-data-repository-method

I see, that bit from your comment (but I was wanting do something like REGEXP (REGEX), I was trying use something like "LIKE IN ('A', 'B')") you should have added it to your question. It was not clear that you were trying to do what you mentioned, just that you were trying an IN operation and it was in error. Anyways, glad that it worked out.
